# arparse output not aligned

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I am using argparse for arguments, I have numbers of argparse statements. I want in the output the capital DELETE should not be print or they should be aligned. 
In my case for another argparse the capital words are not aligned in a single column.

```
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument( '-del'    ,action='store'          ,dest='delete'       , help="Del a POX"
   parser.add_argument( '-a'    ,action='store'          ,dest='add'       , help="add a POX"
   return parser

   python myscript.h -h
   -del DELETE Del a POX
   -a     Add  add a POX
```

Comment: added space in the arguments to align the capital words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your parameters I get:

```
In [417]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [418]: a1=parser.add_argument('-del',dest='delete', help='help')
In [419]: a2=parser.add_argument('-a',dest='add', help='help')
In [420]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-del DELETE] [-a ADD]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  -del DELETE  help
  -a ADD       help
```

The `DELETE` and `ADD` are metavars, standins for the argument that will follow the flag.  In the normal help display they follow immediately after the flag, `-a ADD`.  I don't know what is producing the extra space in '-a     Add  '.

I would have set up your arguments with:

```
In [421]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [422]: a1=parser.add_argument('-d','--delete', help='help')
In [423]: a2=parser.add_argument('-a','--add', help='help')
In [424]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-d DELETE] [-a ADD]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d DELETE, --delete DELETE
                        help
  -a ADD, --add ADD     help
```

And with the `metavar` parameter, here an empty string:

```
In [425]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [426]: a1=parser.add_argument('-d','--delete', metavar='', help='help')
In [427]: a2=parser.add_argument('-a','--add', metavar='', help='help')
In [428]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-d] [-a]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  -d , --delete   help
  -a , --add      help
```

`dest` is normally deduced from the first `--` flag string; but can, as you do, be set explicitly.  `metavar` is derived from the `dest` - usually upper cased - in fact I don't know what produces the `Add` instead of `ADD`.

It aligns the `help` portion of the line, but does not align the matavar part.